# Downloading a s3 bucket object using the url

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, axios

I have an application file in a s3 bucket. I want to when I visit my webpage, it will download the object in the s3 bucket, using the url. I am using axios, but open to other ideas at this point.

I thought just using a simple get route, would cause axios to visit the link to the object and cause the download, since when you visit the link it causes the the file to auto download.

```
 link = `https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-web/file`
    axios.get(link).then((resData)=>{
        console.log(resData);
    })
```

Comment: `window.location.href = link`?

Comment: `document.location.href` = caused the redirect, `window.location.href` worked. Thanks